# Preventing access to databases on self hosted mysql server

Tags: mysql, database, security

Our application uses a sql database for storing data which mustnt be modified by the user.

For now we are using a local sqlite db which is encrypted via [sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) and which gets decrypted on 
application start with a private key set by us. This way the user cant modify any data without knowing 
this key or even load the database in his favourite db browser.

We now want to allow for the database to be on a mysql server. But as far as i understand 
an equal way of securing the data isnt possible. Especially because we want the user to be 
able to host his own server (The same way as he used his "own" local sqlite file) I understand there is a so called "at rest" encryption for innodb in mysql now but this seems to be completely transparent to the user. So if the user connects to the db he doesnt have to enter a key for it to be decrypted but this will happen automatically for him in the background.

Is there a way to allow the user to use its own mysql server but prevent him from modifying 
any database we create on it? Or is this only possible with a server we host ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first give a short comment regarding the method you used until now.

I think that the concept has been wrong in the first place, because it is not secure. The decryption key has to be in the application because otherwise your users would not be able to open the database. As soon as the application runs, a user could extract that key from RAM using well-known methods / tools.

In contrast, when using a server in a locked room, you have *real* safety provided that the server software does not have bugs which allow users to attack it.

Thus, the answer to your question is:

- Yes, it is wise to upgrade to MySQL.
- Use one server for all users which physically is at a place where normal users don't have access to.
- No, do not try to encrypt the MySQL table files on the disk if your only concern is that users shall not be able to change the data.
- Instead, assign access privileges to your central database and tables properly. If the normal users have only read privilege on all tables, they will not have the chance to modify any data via network, but can read all data. As far as I have understood, this is what you want.

Comment: Hm not exactly, sorry if i have been unclear. Thanks for the comment though, we know of the risks but have agreed with the customer that the choosen method is sufficent for a basic version. For a professional version this should be improved upon though. Regarding the database the question was if it is possible that the user/company can be able to use an already existing mysql server they might have in their intranet, so they can simply connect to it via our application but we are still able to ensure they are not able to edit the data.

Comment: but it looks like the only way is to install the mysql server by ourselves within our installation procedures, or am i wrong?

Comment: I think the CEOs of your company and your customer company should have a talk. It should be possible to install *your* database on *their* server and *enforce by some written contract* that *only your admins or their admins* have physical access to that server and that no admin will touch the respective data. If this is not possible, then either install your own MySQL server at their place (but this will never be secure as long as their admins have physical access to the server), or rent a server from some hosting company.